# Counting sort with negative integers?

Tags: c, sorting, counting-sort

I wanna modify my counting sort algorithym to work with negative integers.

here is what i have so far(*segmentation fault*):

```
void counting_sort(int *vet, int max, int min, int n){

  int i, j, C[(max-min)+1], B[n];

  for (i=0;i<=max;i++){
    C[i]=0;
  }

  for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    C[vet[i]-min]++;
  }

  for (i=1;i<=(max-min);i++){
    C[i]=C[i]+C[i-1];
  }

  for (i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
    B[C[(vet[i])-min]-1]=vet[i];
    C[vet[i]-min]--;
  }

  for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%d ",B[i]);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code with gdb? Where does the segfault occur?

Comment: this line seems to be the problem:
B[C[(vet[i])-min]-1]=vet[i]; its trying to access vallues greater than the vector lenght i think

Comment: Using a debugger you can easily find out! When you step through the code, statement by statement, you can also monitor and check the values of all variables, and check that the result of expressions are valid as indexes.

Comment: i have an idea where the problem is (its trying to access vallues greater than the vector lenght) but dont really know how to fix it, i implemented a code using the same logic in C++, and it works fine, but for some reason does not work in c, and unfotunatelly it has to be written in c.

Comment: `for (i=0;i<=max;i++){
    C[i]=0;
  }` is incorrect.  Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This loop looks like it has an off-by-one error in it:

```
for (i=1;i<=(max-min+1);i++){
    C[i]=C[i]+C[i-1];
}
```

Note that the array C has max - min + 1 elements in it, so if you iterate up to *and including* index max - min + 1, you’re writing off the end of the array.

There may be other issues here as well, but I’d start by looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what's causing the segmentation fault but if you want to sort negative numbers using counting sort, you just need to find the lowest negative number in the array and add the absolute value to all values of array temporary. After this, use the normal counting sort algo to sort the array then substract the lowest minimum value from every number in the array obtained.

---

Adding/Subtracting a number from all elements of the array do not affect the result of sorting.

Comment: ... and the approach you describe appears to be exactly what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this to sort in forward order:

```
    int i, j, C[(max-min)+2], B[n];   // ...+2...
    for (i=0;i<=(max-min)+1;i++){     // ...+1...
        C[i]=0;
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        C[vet[i]+1-min]++;            // ...+1...
    }
    for (i=2;i<=(max-min);i++){       // i = 2
        C[i]+=C[i-1];
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){                // 0 to n-1 sort
        B[C[vet[i]-min]++]=vet[i];
    }
```